# Create a chart using Jxl API

Tags: java, jxl

I'm using the Jxl.jar. I'm writing some data on a .xls file and I want to know if actually you can use Jxl to take a range of those data and make a flow chart of them. Thanks for your answers.

```
    File file = new File("datos.xls");
    WritableWorkbook excelBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file);
    WritableSheet excelSheet = excelBook.createSheet("Data", 0);

    excelSheet.addCell(new jxl.write.Number(0, 1, x.getValue()));
    excelSheet.addCell(new jxl.write.Number(0, 2, x.getValue()));
    excelSheet.addCell(new jxl.write.Number(0, 3, x.getValue()));
    excelSheet.addCell(new jxl.write.Number(0, 4, x.getValue()));

    //Make a chart with values.
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try [Apache POI Jar](https://poi.apache.org). Use of that Jar you can make different types of Chart

click to show more info...

[More Info](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/1.x/samples/chartsample.html)